# How to implement terminal scrolling

Tags: c, scroll, terminal, osdev, bare-metal

I've followed the Bare Bones tutorial and created a kernel. I've added some support for terminal scolling, but it hasn't really worked. When I run my final ISO image in VirtualBox, it gives me a critical error. The log files are full of gibberish. Currently, my terminal scrolling function is:

```
void terminal_scroll()
{
    uint8_t attribyte = (0 << 4) | (15 & 0x0F);
    uint16_t blank = 0x20 | (attribyte << 8);

    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0*80; i < 24*80; i++)
        terminal_buffer[i] = terminal_buffer[i + 80]

    for (i = 24*80; i < 25*80; i++)
        terminal_buffer[i] = blank;
}
```

Comment: scrolling looks good to me. are you tyring to print on line 25 (of 0..24)?

Comment: So basically, I'm trying to shift all lines up by one line (thus overwriting the top one) so that the bottom line is empty.

Comment: this line: 'uint8_t attribyte = (0 << 4) | (15 & 0x0F);' the (0<<4) has no effect, as 0, no many how many times shifted is still 0.  this line: 'uint16_t blank = 0x20 | (attribyte << 8);' will raise a compiler event because a 8 bit byte shifted 8 bits is (at best) 0.  suggest: 'uint16_t blank = 0x20 | (0x0F << 8);'

Comment: this code block: 'for (i = 0*80; i < 24*80; i++)' has a few rash assumptions:  1) 0*80 is still 0  2) assumes display is 24 lines, 3) assumes width is 80 characters.

Comment: regarding this line: 'for (i = 24*80; i < 25*80; i++)' you indicated the terminal buffer is only 24x80 in size.  and C begins all array offsets at 0, so '24*80' will point past the end of the buffer.  '25*80' will point WAY past the end of the buffer.  suggest: i=23*80;i < sizeof(terminal_Buffer); i++   It would ease the coding if the terminal buffer were defined as terminal_Buffer[24][80]  then clearing the last line would be: for( i=0;i<80,i++) terminal_Buffer[23][i] = blank;

Comment: to avoid a messy, jumping scroll, it would be a very good idea to keep two images of the screen, while displaying image 1, be updating image 2, then during the 'retrace blanking cycle', swap images.

Comment: All of these suggestions are great so I've decided to rewrite the terminal section using them. While I rewrite the section, I'm going to use the following as a placeholder scrolling function:
`function terminal_scroll()
{
vga_clearscreen();
terminal_row = 0;
terminal_column = 0;
}`

Comment: Please don't do that. Reading from video memory (be it text mode or LFB mode) is extremely slow. Always use a backbuffer to only ever write *to* video memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I did this:

```
void terminal_scroll(){
    for(int i = 0; i < vga_height; i++){
        for (int m = 0; m < vga_width; m++){
            terminal_buffer[i * vga_width + m] = terminal_buffer[(i + 1) * vga_width + m];
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.